# Python: Installing and using Exscript module Windows x86

Tags: python, module

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get Exscript installed. After multiple failed attempts at doing it manually, I installed ActivePython and had success running "pypm install Exscript" from the cmd prompt.

I am now going through the Exscript documentation (found here https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/wiki/Python-API-Tutorial) and if I run the first example script I get an error:

```
>>> from Exscript.util.interact import read_login

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
ImportError: No module named interact
```

So, I understand that this is saying that there is no module interact. How can I check this? Is there a way I can manually add this module? I would love to know WHY this module didnt come with the package, but that may be impossible to answer :)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

- EDIT -

import Exscript.util works but if I try import Exscript.util.Interact I get the error. When I look in util.py I see an entry that says  "from FooLib import Interact". I first thought it may just be a capitalization error (Exscript.util.interact vs util.Interact) but neither of those work. I am not sure where to go from here... :(

- EDIT -

I have posted this question on the developers forums, hopefully he will have an answer for us. https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/issues/15

- EDIT -

The developer suggested that I was using an old version and told me to download the latest. I had struggled installing the module manually so I googled how to easily install py modules. I found a writeup on easy_install.exe. I ran "c:\Python26>easy_install C:\Users\support\Desktop\lou\knipknap-exscript-v2.1-70-gf5583f3.tar.gz" from the cmd prompt, the module was installed (no errors) and now when i run the script it works.

Next challenge will be how to get these scripts to run as stand-alone exe's on users computers without Python installed :)

THANK YOU to everyone to commented I truely appreciate your help.

Lou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way packages are installed is as directories.  So check your `site-packages` directory for an `Exscript` directory, and inside that there should be a `util` directory, and inside that there should be an `interact.py` file.  Look for similar spellings in case the tutorial misspelled something.

Comment: Nothing in site-packages under the Python26 install dir. I ran help() on Exscript and found it is installed under c:\users\support\appdata\roaming\python\python26\site-packages\exscript. From there there is a util.py and util.pyc but there is not a util directory. I did, however, find Interact.py under the \Exscript\FooLib directory. What can I do with that?

Comment: The wonderful thing about python is that the pre-compiled .py file should be there for the util.py.  The assumtion I would be making is that in util.py there's a class called interact and within that class there's a module called read_login.  You can open it up youself and check it out.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I have found the solution (thanks to your help!); please see above. It turns out I was just using an older version of the module.